# Best Practices for Sending Extensive Filters in GET Requests Without Exceeding Header Limits

Tags: rest, post, get, restful-url

I'm working on an application that allows users to filter by location. In order to do this, I'm adding my city filters into a query parameter. For example, if someone selects `California` I would encode it in base64 and then add the filters to my query parameter. Here's the filter object that gets encoded:

```js
[{city: "San Francisco", state: "California", country: "USA"}, {...}, {...}]
```

Here's what the request will look like after encoding:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/v1/companies?offset=0&limit=50&locs=W3siY2l0eSI6IkFsYW1lZGEiLCJzdGF0ZSI6IkNhbGlmb3JuaWEiLCJjb3VudHJ5IjoiVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcyJ9LHsiY2l0eSI6IkFuYWhlaW0iLCJzdGF0ZSI6IkNhbGlm...
```

However, after a certain number of filters, I run up against header limits (i.e. I can't fit more information into the request header).

What's the best-practice way of handling this? Should I send a `POST` request instead, or is that frowned upon?

[image]

FYI — Users can click into a state and select/unselected specific cities. For example, someone could click into `California` and uncheck `San Francisco` and `Los Angeles` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request URI is not considered a header, but you still may run into limits. Usually it's recommended to stay under 2048 bytes.

If you go above this, switch to a different HTTP method (`QUERY`, `POST`) and use the request body. `QUERY` is more appropriate for read operations, supported by browsers but not yet by every server. `POST` is a good second choice.